# How to add word prediction feature to custom iOS keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-keyboard, quicktype

I am working on custom keyboard app and just going to implement prediction feature. As I know, apple don't allow use QuickType feature on custom keyboard.

Then what is the best solution to add word prediction feature to custom iOS keyboard extension ?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Did you got any solution on this ? I am seeking the same

Comment: @DeepakSasindran Did you get any solution for this?